# WordPress PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-leaks, fatal-error

I am working on Multi Network WordPress website. On admin panel when try to go to Network Admin > any sub menu
[image]

i got the following error

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/customer/www/mydomainname.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6940
and on that line we have the following function
[image]

already added the following code in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '5000M' );
ini_set('memory_limit', '20000M');
```

Comment: Usually this is a hosting provider issue.

Comment: Thank you, there was a memory leak in one of our plugin, which cause that issue.